# Get Group Details from Person or Group field using REST API?

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api, groups, person-or-group

REST API I am using:

```
_api/web/lists/getbytitle('listname')/items(100)?$select=Initiator/EMail,RAReviewers/EMail&$expand=Initiator/Id,RAReviewers/Id
```

In this `RaReviewers` column is a Person/Group. It contains one Person and one group, if all are persons it works fine, but with having group it's not working.

Comment: What are you trying to fetch from column? Are you getting any error while using this API?

Comment: [Solved] I replaced RAReviewers/EMail - RAReviewers/Name and it returns key value which works for me

Answer (score 1):

Try using this:

```
_api/web/lists/getbytitle('listname')/items(100)?$select=Initiator/EMail,RAReviewers/EMail&$expand=Initiator,RAReviewers
```

Above is working fine for me in case of person or group.

**Example**:

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('TestList')/items(1)?$select=TestPersonField/Title,TestPersonField/EMail&$expand=TestPersonField
```

**Output**: Below is part of response returned from above API call

```
<entry>
    <content type="application/xml">
        <m:properties>
            <d:Title>Ganesh Sanap</d:Title>
            <d:EMail>gsanap@tenant.onmicrosoft.com</d:EMail>
        </m:properties>
    </content>
</entry>
<entry>
    <content type="application/xml">
        <m:properties>
            <d:Title>SPConnect Members</d:Title>
            <d:EMail>SPConnect@tenant.onmicrosoft.com</d:EMail>
        </m:properties>
    </content>
</entry>
```

Where `SPConnect Members` is a Microsoft 365 group name.

**Note**: This will not work for SharePoint groups as they don't have **Email** property.